# AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'MEDIA_URL'

Tags: python, html, django, pycharm

So I am practicing an ecommerce website in django and I encountered a problem in rendering the images of the my products. I followed my reference very well and his code worked but mine didnt.

These are my references:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLbkL.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3dY6.png

My reference worked and got this result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSez1.png

This is my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

This is my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('store.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URl, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And I got this result:
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'MEDIA_URl'

and my website crashed.

Can someone enlighten my stupid tiny brain please?

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo: `settings.MEDIA_URl` => `settings.MEDIA_URL`.